# How do I limit the options inside a select based on a selection made right before with sql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I need delimit the options inside a select tag according to the choices I made on the select made right before this one. My code is:

This is the sequency:

> Category -> Subcategory -> Product Type

On code:

```
 <tr>
    <td align="center"><b>Categoria do produto:</b></td>
    <td>
        <select name="categoria_produto" id="">
        <option>Selecione a categoria:</option>
        <?php
            
            $buscar_categ = "SELECT * FROM categorias";

            $run_categ = mysqli_query($con, $buscar_categ);

            while ($row_categs = mysqli_fetch_array($run_categ)) {

                $categ_id = $row_categs['categ_id'];
                $categ_titulo = $row_categs['categ_titulo'];

                echo "<option value='$categ_id'>$categ_titulo</option>";
            }

        ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Subcategoria do produto:</b></td>
<td>
    <select name="subcateg_produto" id="">
        <option>Selecione a subcategoria:</option>
        <?php
            
            $buscar_subcateg = "SELECT * FROM subcateg WHERE ";

            $run_subcateg = mysqli_query($con, $buscar_subcateg);

            while ($row_subcateg = mysqli_fetch_array($run_subcateg)) {

                $subcateg_id = $row_subcateg['subcateg_id'];
                $subcateg_name = $row_subcateg['subcateg_name'];

                echo "<option value='$subcateg_id'>$subcateg_name</option>";
            }

        ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Tipo do produto:</b></td>
<td>
    <select name="tipo_produto" id="">
        <option>Selecione o tipo:</option>
        <?php
            
            $buscar_tipoprod = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod";

            $run_tipoprod = mysqli_query($con, $buscar_tipoprod);

            while ($row_tipoprod = mysqli_fetch_array($run_tipoprod)) {

                $tipoprod_id = $row_tipoprod['tipoprod_id'];
                $tipoprod_name = $row_tipoprod['tipoprod_name'];

                echo "<option value='$tipoprod_id'>$tipoprod_name</option>";
            }

        ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

This code is showing all the rows that exists inside each column which is being called... That's quite OK, but to a perfect approach I need delimit what is being shown according to what I select before.

Imagine this:

> Category => Market / Subcategory (options inside market category) =>
> Food / Type (options inside food) => Cereals

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are misusing the word "delimit" — if not I am totally confused by your question.

Comment: check this out: https://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/

Comment: delimit, limit, restrict... I serched more and I found something called combobox that is what I am looking for

Comment: That's it what I was looking for, thanks... Do you know any other way of doing it only using sql and php?

Comment: you'd have to use javascript at some point if you want to dynamically alter the menus